Adding a tooltip component via JavaScript
I'm trying to add tooltips in a custom style to various components.
What I'm doing right now is

fetching the components that should have a tooltip, e.g.

    var checkbox = document.querySelector("#someForm .ui-selection-column .ui-chkbox");
    if (checkbox && (!checkbox.nextElementSibling || !checkbox.nextElementSibling.classList.contains("my-tooltip"))) {
        createTooltipComponent(checkbox, "This is my tooltip!", false);
    }


Creating a new tooltip component and adding it as a direct sibling

function createTooltipComponent(component, text, tooltipShouldBeToTheLeft) {
    console.log("Create tooltip compoment for ");
    console.log(component);
    var tooltipComponent = document.createElement('div');
    tooltipComponent.innerHTML = text;
    tooltipComponent.classList.add("my-tooltip");
    
    if (tooltipShouldBeToTheLeft) {
        tooltipKomponente.classList.add("my-tooltip-to-the-left");
    } else {
        tooltipKomponente.classList.add("my-tooltip-to-the-right");
    }

    component.parentNode.insertBefore(tooltipComponent, component.nextSibling);
}


Style the tooltip component

.my-tooltip {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #1e3a61;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 12px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.my-tooltip-to-the-left::after,
.my-tooltip-to-the-right::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    top: 36%;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.my-tooltip-to-the-left::after {
    border-left-color: #1e3a61;
    left: 100%;
}

.my-tooltip-to-the-right::before {
    border-right-color: #1e3a61;
    right: 100%;
}

I'm not yet bothering with the fact that the tooltip div should only be visible when hovering over the original component. I'm still trying to figure out the styling - the tooltip should be always fully visible, but depending on the component the tooltip is for (which sometimes has a certain display or position attribute), the tooltip div is often rendered beneath the div instead of next to it. Also, if the parent container for both components is too small, the tooltip will be cut off. Is there a way to style the tooltip component via CSS (and without styling the component the tooltip is for) in a way that makes the tooltip always turn up fully and right next to it? (Ideally so that the tooltip is to the left OR to the right of it, depending on the class.)
